# What is preventing Twitter from scaling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, scale

The beauty of fast paced frameworks like Rails is that it allows you to deploy quickly- sometimes that comes with a price of having to find ways to scale later.
Twitter seem to still be having problems scaling, even though they have been working on this problem for well over a year.

I was wondering - what is preventing them from scaling properly?
Is it rails? Database problems? API complexity? Monkeys in the data center?

Any ideas?

Comment: I blame Justin Bieber and the spam bots.

Comment: Isn't this going to be pretty much speculation / guessswork and not really an answerable programming question?  Unless any twitter developers want to spill the beans here...

Comment: I think it's a interresting question about scalability, and I expect to see some architecture tips about how to handle such a scalability problems that happens even with basic application.
Everyone can build a twitter in a short amount of time that handles one up to fifty people. I think only few could do so for millions up to infinite. I would be definitely interrested to have information about it.

Comment: Serg - of course this is guesswork and not a programming question. But informed guess work can lead to interesting conclusions.